# Getting Newsticker.el to use rss feeds with login credentials

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to use Newsticker.el also on some internal rss feeds which require login credentials. Since all what newsticker does is getting wget to fetch the feeds I tought it would be possible to simply define the user name and password in the wget confiuration part of newsticker.el

So I configured the following in my init.el

```
'(newsticker-url-list (quote (("RSS FEED" "https://to.feed.com/timeline?format=rss"
              nil nil ("--user=<username>" "--password=<password>" "-q" "-O" "-")))
```

Feeding the `--user`  and `--password` options directly to wget works fine but not not within the newsticker.el setup. Anyone tried something similar before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newsticker can use wget, indeed, but it can also use Emacs's URL library instead.  So you might want to check `newsticker-retrieval-method` to see which one is used.

Comment: Stefan, you were right. It was set to "intern" and setting it to "extern" now triggers wget and uses the access credentials. Thanks! :)